# C - pipe without using popen

Tags: c, pipe, popen

how can I transform this:

```
FILE *f;
char in_buffer[80];
f=popen("command","r");
fgets(in_buffer,sizeof(in_buffer),f)
```

without using `popen()`, but only `pipe()` or other instruction?

Comment: With `fork`, `execve`, `dup2`, `open` and `close`. Look them up.

Comment: no homework. just wanted to know what exactly popen does and how to implement it with pipe

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's my simple implementation, with comments explaining what's being done.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *
my_popen (const char *cmd)
{
    int fd[2];
    int read_fd, write_fd;
    int pid;               

    /* First, create a pipe and a pair of file descriptors for its both ends */
    pipe(fd);
    read_fd = fd[0];
    write_fd = fd[1];

    /* Now fork in order to create process from we'll read from */
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        /* Child process */

        /* Close "read" endpoint - child will only use write end */
        close(read_fd);

        /* Now "bind" fd 1 (standard output) to our "write" end of pipe */
        dup2(write_fd,1);

        /* Close original descriptor we got from pipe() */
        close(write_fd);

        /* Execute command via shell - this will replace current process */
        execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", cmd, NULL);

        /* Don't let compiler be angry with us */
        return NULL;
    } else {
        /* Parent */

        /* Close "write" end, not needed in this process */
        close(write_fd);

        /* Parent process is simpler - just create FILE* from file descriptor,
           for compatibility with popen() */
        return fdopen(read_fd, "r");
    }
}

int main ()
{
    FILE *p = my_popen ("ls -l");
    char buffer[1024];
    while (fgets(buffer, 1024, p)) {
        printf (" => %s", buffer);
    }
    fclose(p);
}
```

Notes:

1. Thir code supports only `"r"` mode of `popen`. Implementing other modes, namely `"w"` mode is left as an exercise for the reader.
2. System functions used in this example may fail - error handling is left as an exercise for the reader.
3. Implementation of `pclose` is left as an exercise for the reader - see `close`, `waiptid`, and `fclose`.

If you want to look at real impementations, you can look into sources of [OSX](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-186/gen.subproj/popen.c), [GNU glibc](http://koala.cs.pub.ro/lxr/glibc/libio/iopopen.c) and [OpenSolaris](https://github.com/joyent/illumos-joyent/blob/master/usr/src/cmd/mailx/popen.c), among others.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `close(1);` is unnecessary as `dup2()` will do so if needed. OTOH, after `dup2()` a `close(write_fd)` might be useful...

Comment: Can you please explain me the meaning of: 
dup2(write_fd,1); ?

Comment: According to standards, file descriptor no 1 is standard output. By default it's connected to some kind of terminal. `write_fd`, on the other hand, is writeble end of a pipe connecting child and parent processes. We want anything sent to fd 1 to go to our parent process via created pipe instead of terminal, so call to `dup2` is necesary. See `man dup2` for details.

Comment: Note: `fork()` will return `-1` on error. This should be handled!

Comment: @johannes see note #2